# How to set the frames of the subviews only when the parentView frame is set?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, frame, bounds

Basically I am creating a Tinder-esque layout with UIViews stack over on top of each other. In order to get shadows behind a rounded UIView I am creating a custom UIView called `MainSwipeCardView` which is made of two views. One is called `SwipeCardView` and behind it is a `ShadowView.`
Then I am sequentially creating an instance of MainSwipeCardView and set it's frame.

```
   func addCardFrame(index: Int, cardView: MainSwipeCardView){
    cardsView.append(cardView)

    var cardViewFrame = bounds
    let horizontalInset = (CGFloat(index) * self.horizontalInset)
    let verticalInset = CGFloat(index) * self.verticalInset

    cardViewFrame.size.width -= 2 * horizontalInset
    cardViewFrame.origin.x += horizontalInset
    cardViewFrame.origin.y += verticalInset
    cardView.frame = cardViewFrame
}
```

The frame is set depending upon the index of the card. The top one is going to be the largest, then the one in the bottom will have some horizontal and vertical inset etc.

As you can see, I am setting `cardView.frame = cardViewFrame` - `cardViewFrame` being the frame that we have calculated above. The issue however is that cardView is a custom view of class MainSwipeCardView. The content inside this view (a simple Shadow UIView and custom SwipeCardView) needs to have its frame set according to the frame of the parent view. I am not able to do this correctly.

**Question:**
How to set the frame of two custom subviews only after the parent view's frame is set. Since the parent view's frame is different(it depends on the index) I want the size of the subviews to accordingly change as well.

Comment: Have you considered using autolayout? This solves a lot of dynamic frame problems.

Comment: Agreed. Got it working using autolayout! Thanks:)

Comment: Instead of adjusting the frame, consider using a 3D transform and setting the z position of the view with perspective applied.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make use of property Observers

```
let parventViewFram = parentView.bounds { didSet {
   //add your custom Subviews or edit your custom subviews by calling layoutSubviews
}}
```

make sure you initialize your parentView before accessing its property